# Change permalink when page category selected in admin

Tags: permalinks, wp-admin, hooks

I'm using the Events Manager plugin which uses a custom post type of 'events' and a custom taxonomy of 'event-categories'.  One of my events categories is 'Short courses'.

When I check this category (in admin) I want the default of /events/page-title to change to /course/page-title, and revert when the category is unchecked.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided on a different approach.  Keep the default permalinks in admin, then add a rewrite to allow /course:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^course/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?event=$matches[1]', 'top'); // single event
```

Then I can update my theme templates with the course/ urls where needed.